# How to send data from scrapy to flask server?

Tags: python, flask, scrapy, scrapyd

I have a flask sever running on `localhost:5000` and a scrapyd running on `localhost:6800` with only one spider. My problem is that i have scraped some data and i want to send the data to the flask server for some processing over the extracted data. 
 If the data had to be send to some database, say MongoDB then we could have  used `pymongo.Connection` in item pipeline. Is there any similar approach for sending the data to flask server ?

Comment: May be you should try to send http-request to your flask server?

Comment: I tried this, but it gives another problem. We have to return some value from the flask route otherwise it raises ValueError. But, here i don't want to receive anything back to scrapyd

Comment: If there is solution for that ValueError, then it would be great.

Comment: Did you read this http://stackoverflow.com/questions/25034123/flask-value-error-view-function-did-not-return-a-response?

Comment: Well, that value error is not coming now. I just returned any random string. But, there is still something that i can't understand. I am getting all the data but, the following i can't understand. First it gives 200 then 400 why?
127.0.0.1 - - [27/Aug/2015 14:33:08] "POST /reviews HTTP/1.1" 200 -
127.0.0.1 - - [27/Aug/2015 14:33:08] "POST /reviews HTTP/1.1" 400 -
Is it because i am returning a random string ?

Comment: Leave it. It's fine now. I had made two requests at different positions. One of them was wrong.