# Flask - window.location not working on Firefox (latest versions)

Tags: javascript, flask, jinja2, query-string, window.location

In my Flask App, I'm making a bunch of `a hrefs` that will redirect the user to another page that contains an input form. This input-form will be pre-filled via `this.innerHTML` It works perfectly on all browsers except for firefox, where I get the `ValueError: View function did not return a response` .

```
{% for x in text %}
  <p>{{ x["address"] }} : <strong><a href="">{{ x["car_park_no"] }}</a></strong> </p>
{% endfor %}
```

This is particularly confusing for me as I've checked everywhere on Google and SO and tried all the possible fixes that could be Firefox related... `(window.location)` vs `(window.location.href)` vs `(window.location.assign)` vs `make function return false`

I understand that there are questions on SO regarding how this error only occurs when functions do not return a response - However my function here already returns a response. And this error does not occur on Chrome/Internet Explorer/Safari/Edge, only on Firefox.

```
<script>
  // add query strings
  window.onload = function() {
    var elements = document.getElementsByTagName('a');
      for(var i = 0, len = elements.length; i < len; i++) {
        elements[i].onclick = function () {
        event.preventDefault(); 
        window.location = "/lotfinder?address=" + this.innerHTML;
      }, false;
    }
  }
</script>
```

Any help would be appreciated, do leave a comment if you require more code snippets.

edit: Code at /lotfinder endpoint

```
    <h1>carpark.py</h1>
      <form action = "/carpark" method = "POST">
         <p>Carpark No: <input type = "text" id="carpark-input" name = "Carpark" required></p>
         <p><input type = "submit" value = "submit"></p>
      </form>
   </body>
  <script>

  const carparkInput = document.getElementById("carpark-input");
  // use new URLSearchParams API instead of ugly regex querystring parsing
  window.onload = function() {
    var urlParams = new URLSearchParams(window.location.search);
    carparkInput.value = urlParams.get('address');
  }

</script>
```

Above is HTML, below is the Handler

```
@app.route('/lotfinder',methods = ['POST', 'GET'])
def car1():
    if request.method == 'GET':
        return render_template("car1.html")
```

Answer (score 0):

I think you are assigning `false` to all your click event handlers. Try this:

```
 // add query strings
 window.onload = function() {
   var elements = document.getElementsByTagName('a');
     for(var i = 0, len = elements.length; i < len; i++) {
       elements[i].onclick = function () {
       event.preventDefault(); 
       window.location = "/lotfinder?address=" + this.innerHTML;
     };
   }
 }
```

The `ValueError: View function did not return a response` error is returned by Flask when one of your functions does not return a value. See [Flask Value error view function did not return a response](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/25034123/flask-value-error-view-function-did-not-return-a-response)

You can try editing your endpoint function like so:

```
@app.route('/lotfinder',methods = ['POST', 'GET'])
def car1():
    if request.method == 'GET':
        return render_template("car1.html")
    return 'OK'
```

Comment: yeah i thought that too, but the error of `ValueError: View function did not return a response` still persists, weird thats its Firefox-only

Comment: Done @tomcek112

Comment: edited according to your answer, even removed the `if request.method ==` handler but the err 500 persists, interestingly enough, on Firefox, the endpoint is a `GET /address` instead of a `GET /lotfinder?querystringhere` on other browsers

Answer (score 0):

Just pass **event** into anonymous function as parameter

```
elements[i].onclick = function ( event ) {
```

Thanks

Comment: hi @vinesh what does passing event into the function do? tried but 500 persists on firefox