# issue in fetching one element in mongodb rest api using python

Tags: python, mongodb, flask, rest

I am trying to fetch the data for 1 id and I am getting Nonetye object in return.

```
@app.route('/api/dd/<id>',methods=['GET','PUT','DELETE'])
def api_each_bmat(id):       
    if request.method == "GET":
        music_obj = music.objects(id=id).first()
```

**error**

```
[2021-08-04 15:10:35,454] ERROR in app: Exception on /api/bmat/"T0350190010" [GET]
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "C:\Users\rishi\anaconda3\lib\site-packages\flask\app.py", line 2447, in wsgi_app
    response = self.full_dispatch_request()
  File "C:\Users\rishi\anaconda3\lib\site-packages\flask\app.py", line 1953, in full_dispatch_request
    return self.finalize_request(rv)
  File "C:\Users\rishi\anaconda3\lib\site-packages\flask\app.py", line 1968, in finalize_request
    response = self.make_response(rv)
  File "C:\Users\rishi\anaconda3\lib\site-packages\flask\app.py", line 2097, in make_response
    raise TypeError(
TypeError: The view function did not return a valid response. The function either returned None or ended without a return statement.
127.0.0.1 - - [04/Aug/2021 15:10:35] "GET /api/bmat/%22T0350190010%22 HTTP/1.1" 500 -
```

Comment: Where's your id variable coming from in `music.objects(id=id).first()` ?
The parameter you need seems to be `iswc`.

Comment: @welyweloo that was just a typo while I was pasting code here.

Comment: when I am passing the right id I am getting nontype return

Comment: Ok, shall you make a return at the end of your view function ? See accepted answer here : https://stackoverflow.com/questions/25034123/flask-value-error-view-function-did-not-return-a-response